# convert returned value from ng-model

Tags: angularjs

i wrote this angularjs code but the problem is when i make the input type to number every thing is ok and the number converted to hexa even i make change the number manually without increase or decrease buttons , but when i make input type to text the result is just same number of text input without converted it.
why ?? and sorry for my english !!

this is my code :

```
<html>
 <head> 
   <title> convert to hex </title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8 /angular.min.js"></script>

</head> 

<body> 
  <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="namectrl">
      <input ng-model = 'number' type="text">
        <h3> {{hexa(number)}} </h3>
  </div>

     <script>
   var app = angular.module("myapp" ,[]);
   app.controller("namectrl" , function($scope)
   {
     $scope.hexa = function(x) {
       return x.toString(16);
        };
   }); 

     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $scope.hexa = function(x) {
          return Number(x).toString(16);
 };
```

Working [`App`](http://plnkr.co/edit/LXxAWTciMVpnxi4moWtt?p=preview)